# How to temperature throttle my Windows 11 laptop?

Tags: battery, power-management, performance-tuning

How can I temp throttle my laptop?  I'm on Windows 11. I want it to be as cool as possible.  I don't need performance, either when plugged in or on battery.  Are there registry settings or a third party tool?

End goal is that the keyboard and palm rest feels does not feel hot.

Comment: In Windows 10, there are Power Options, q.v., to specify maximum CPU usage. Hopefully, those options have not been removed from Window 11.

Comment: Are you worried about noise (high fan speed)? Are you comfortable navigating around the BIOS (to underclock your CPU)?

Comment: can you help us better understand what your end goals are? "Cool" in an arbitrary sense is rarely a goal in-and-of-itself.

Answer (score 3):

You may lower the CPU performance, which will reduce power consumption,
which will make the computer cooler.

This is done in
*Power Options > Change plan settings > Change advanced power settings*,
and at branch "Processor power management" set the
Maximum processor state Settings to less than 100%.

Note that if your computer is overheating, even a few percent less
will make a difference. However, hardware solutions will be better
in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Metabox (Clevo) laptop that started overheating (freeze and restart) when gaming in summer. I cleaned the fans and changed the thermal paste which didn't resolve it.

Solution: I throttled the CPU using the a Windows 10/11 custom power plan.

I set the maximum to 98% which reduced my CPU from 4Ghz to 2Ghz (perhaps disabling turbo boost). You can see the Ghz in the task manager's CPU tab. I haven't been negatively impacted by the reduction.

You can create a custom power plan by the following steps

1. Open Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Power Options
2. Click the "Create a power plan" button from the left pane
3. Pick a base plan to create template from
4. Give it a name
5. Save it
6. Find the plan, modify it and select advanced options
7. There will be options there to limit the CPU. I limited the max CPU to 98%

Comment: This is helpful, but I think it needs a few more details and perhaps some formatting. Where do you find these power options, for instance, and where in those options did you make these changes?

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://www.majorgeeks.com/content/page/how_to_add_or_remove_maximum_processor_frequency.html) explains where to find the option, and also how to enable it, as it may be hidden by default.

Comment: Welcome to SU. You should provide context for the link to preserve the information. Please see [How to write a good answe](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [Help](https://superuser.com/help), then [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1774742/edit) your question accordingly. As a new user it's a good idea to check the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and Asking and Answering -questions in the Help center to learn how the site works. Reviewing some older questions with [accepted answers](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) also helps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1179243)